# How can I tell if my code is running inside a Console or desktop application?

Tags: realbasic, xojo

How can I tell whether my RealBasic code is running inside a Console or desktop application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this conditional sentence:

```
#if TargetHasGUI then     
    ' It's running in a desktop app
#else
    ' It's running in a console app
#endif
```

Comment: Be aware that Web Apps return True for `TargetHasGUI` as well.

Comment: Correction: Web Apps return False